# Add custom error page for static directory in nuxt 2

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, nuxt.js

When you navigate to a non-existent page, you get the default 404 error page, but if you navigate to a non-existent static resource, say `/resource.txt`, stored at `/static/resource.txt`, all you get is the browser's error page. How do I add a custom error page to static resources in nuxt 2?

I have tried extending the router in nuxt.config.js, but that did not work. The regular method for adding a custom error page only works for pages it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error.vue in the layouts folder?

Comment: Currently it is not an answer. There are comments to clarify issue

Comment: This does not help, sadly